# With readline, how am I supposed to input a digit N times using numeric arguments?

Tags: readline

Readline has the so-called 'numeric arguments' that repeats the following command several times, e.g. <kbd>M-5 a</kbd> will insert `aaaaa`. But <kbd>M-5 9</kbd> won't insert `99999`. Is there any way to achieve this except typing it literally?

EDIT: I mean the GNU Readline library.

Comment: `readline` is a statement of what language?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the GNU Readline library.